# Edge Detection for high resolution pictures

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to locate three objects in my image and crop the sherd out. Any way that I can detect the edges better? This is the code I use to detect objects.

```
def getEdgedImg(img):
    kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
    eroded = cv2.erode(img, kernel)
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(eroded, 3)
    med_val = np.median(eroded)
    lower = int(max(0, 0.5*med_val))
    upper = int(min(255, 1.3*med_val))
    edged = cv2.Canny(blur, lower, upper)
    return edged

edged = getEdgedImg(img)
_, contours= cv2.findContours(edged ,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
for cnt in contours: 
        if cv2.contourArea(colour_cnts[i]) > 400: 
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(colour_cnts[i])
            cv2.rectangle(img2, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('hi', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am currently doing image processing in my raw images. I have been looking for a few methods to improve the results but still, it doesn't work very well for some photos.
[image]

edge detected:

[image]

Comment: What edges are you after exactly ?  The one's from the stone ? And do you really want the edges or do you want the area of it ?

Comment: First I need to find the bounding boxes (x,y,w,h) of the stone and the cards, then I need to crop the stone out and the last step is to find a mask of the stone. All these require Canny to find edges...

Comment: None of these require edges, they'll even only make you life harder in this case. findContours runs on a binary image, white for the pixel of your object. Use thresholding to binarize. But as @MarkSetchell mentioned, with a weak contrast between background and object that's not gonna be too easy. Should have put that stone on a pink or green cloth or such.

Comment: ' findContours runs on a binary image, white for the pixel of your object. Use thresholding to binarize.' Could you elaborate more on how to do it? I'm new to openCV

Comment: See the answer just posted :)

Answer (score 2):

Had a shot at it, but as expected the weak background contrast is giving trouble, as does the directed lighting. Just checking the stone right now, but the script should give you the tools to find the two reference cards as well. If you want to show the intermediate images, see the comments in the script.

Do you have the original image in another format then JPG by chance ? The color compression in the file is really not helping with extraction.

[image: best Result]

```
import cv2

# get image
img = cv2.imread("<YouPathHere>")

# extract stone shadow in RGB
chB, chG, chR = cv2.split(img)

threshShadow = 48
imgChanneldiff = chR-chB
imgshadow =  cv2.threshold(imgChanneldiff,threshShadow,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
#cv2.namedWindow("imgshadow", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
#cv2.imshow("imgshadow", imgshadow)

# extract stone together with shadow in HSV
imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
threshHue = 10
chH, chS, chV = cv2.split(imgHSV)
imgbin = cv2.threshold(chH,threshHue,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
#cv2.namedWindow("imgbin", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
#cv2.imshow("imgbin", imgbin)


imgResultMask = imgbin - imgshadow
MorphKernelSize = 25;
imgResultMask = cv2.erode(imgResultMask, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, [MorphKernelSize,MorphKernelSize]))
imgResultMask = cv2.dilate(imgResultMask, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, [MorphKernelSize,MorphKernelSize]))
cv2.namedWindow("imgResultMask", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("imgResultMask", imgResultMask)

contours = cv2.findContours(imgResultMask,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (255,125,0), 3)

for c in contours:
    cv2.rectangle(img, cv2.boundingRect(c), (0,125,255))

cv2.namedWindow("img", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("img", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask why did you split the channels?

Comment: Like these few lines: 
```
imgChanneldiff = chR-chB
```
```
chH, chS, chV = cv2.split(imgHSV)
imgbin = cv2.threshold(chH,threshHue,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
imgResultMask = imgbin - imgshadow```

Comment: findContours() works only on single channel (= greyvalue value), binary images (they don't need to be binary exactly, but the get treated as such). The whole shenanigans with subtracting and thresholding are there to get an image with a decent contrast between the stone, its shadow on top and the brighter lit background on the sides. I needed both the RGB as well as the HSV representation to do that here.